# Formula for swapping the choice in a drop down with a numerical value

Tags: calculated-column-formula, formula

I've got a SP drop down column which contains options like:

1. Doesn't align to current priorities
2. Somewhat aligns to current priorities
3. Aligns strongly with current priorities

I want to assign all of these a numerical value so in this case:

1. 0
2. 5
3. 10

So that these values can be used in a calculated field later. What's the best way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula in your calculated column:

```
=IF([Choice]="Doesn't align to current priorities","0",IF([Choice]="Somewhat aligns to current priorities","5",IF([Choice]="Aligns strongly with current priorities","10","-")))
```

Here, `[Choice]` is the column from which formula compares the values.

See the values in my list view:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Dikesh Gandhi I gave that a try: 

=IF([[S1]="Doesn't align to either set of objectives","0",IF([S1]="Aligns to 1 objective in the XXX Single Departmental Plan","10", IF([S1]="Aligns to 1 of XXX Priorities","15","-"))) 

I set the data type returned to number but I'm getting an error saying that the formula refers to a column that does not exist.

Comment: I am assuming that `[S1]` is your choice type column in your list and this formula you are adding in calculated column.

Comment: Yes, I want to use the values assigned to the drop down choices in another Calculated Field

Comment: It seems you have an extra bracket in the start of your formula: [[S1]

Comment: Dikesh' solution worked after a bit of trouble shooting. I took it back to one choice and built from there. Also took the last "-". So for anyone else looking to solve this, it was:

=IF([Choice] = "Whatever's in the list","5") or … "Whatever's in the list","5",IF([Choice] = ….pretty much what he said with some tweaks